XSLT: How to split strings for multiple fields simultaneously
I've seen a number of posts about using tokenize() to split strings, but they all involve a single field.  I have a slightly different situation and I'm not sure how to approach it.
My XML can resemble something like this:
<somefield>
    <code>A,B,C</code>
    <description>Description of A; Description of B; Description of C</description>
</somefield>

I want to transform that into something like this:
{
  "somefield": [
    {
      "code": "A",
      "description": "Description of A"
    },
    {
      "code": "B",
      "description": "Description of B"
    },
    {
      "code": "C",
      "description": "Description of C"
    }
  ]
}

I don't quite see how to split both fields simultaneously like that.
Any ideas?

Please pick either XSLT 1.0 or 2.0, not both.

That's not a valid JSON, is it?

I apologize.  I picked multiple versions of XSLT because I was interested in solutions in either version.

No, it's not valid JSON.  It's a toy example and I forgot to remove the extra comment.  I'll fix it if SO lets me.

It still needs to be wrapped in curly braces.

An XSLT 1.0 solution would have to be radically different - unless your processor happens to support tokenizing as an extension function. See an example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62276436/3016153

In XSLT 2.0 you could do something like
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/somefield">
    <array key="somefield">
        <xsl:variable name="descr" select="tokenize(description, ';')"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(code, ',')">
            <xsl:variable name="i" select="position()"/>
            <map>
                <string key="code">
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </string>
                <string key="description">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$descr[$i]"/>
                </string>
            </map>  
        </xsl:for-each>
    </array>    
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

to get:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<array key="somefield">
   <map>
      <string key="code">A</string>
      <string key="description">Description of A</string>
   </map>
   <map>
      <string key="code">B</string>
      <string key="description"> Description of B</string>
   </map>
   <map>
      <string key="code">C</string>
      <string key="description"> Description of C</string>
   </map>
</array>

(Sorry, I don't have the time to adjust this to output JSON.)

I was able to tweak this to do what I needed.  Thank you so much.

In 3.0 you could do
  array {
    for-each-pair(tokenize(code, ','),
                  tokenize(description, ';'),
                  function($x, $y) { 
                    map{"code": $x, "description": $y}
                  })
  }


Is there a way to extend this to 3 or more sequences?

@y.arazim, yes, you could use e.g.  example fold-left

This is so elegant.
